# [MySQL]How to count rows with specific grouping IN the selection clause

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, count

I have a table like so (MySQL):

```
  CREATE TABLE `UsageGUI_datarecord` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `device_id` varchar(12) NOT NULL,
  `dr_timestamp` datetime(6) NOT NULL,
  `country_code` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `usage` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
  )ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=11718343 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8$$
```

It is a big table containing data usage records of many devices scattered around the world. Please note that 1 device can have many data records per hour.
Example:
[image]

I want to get from this table, the number of devices connected simultaneously per hour per country_code.
If a device sent a data record in an hour, then it is enough to determine that this device was connected in that hour (I want the query to count this device only once in that hour, regardless of how many records it sent during that hour).
So I need to somehow group LEFT(dr_timestamp, 13) inside a COUNT(device_id) clause and I have no idea how to do such a thing.
Can anyone help?
Thank you very much :)

Comment: Have you tried https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_count-distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for hour you could use the hour() function so for today  you could use

```
select count(distinct device_id), country_code, hour(dr_timestamp) hour
from UsageGUI_datarecord 
where date(dr_timestamp) =CURDATE()
group country_code, hour 
order by country_code, hour
```

for each days

```
select count(distinct device_id), country_code, hour(dr_timestamp) hour, 
      year(dr_timestamp) year , month(dr_timestamp) month , day(dr_timestamp) day
from UsageGUI_datarecord 
where date(dr_timestamp) =CURDATE()
group country_code, hour, year, month,day
```

Comment: The DISTINCT() works! Thanks @P.Salon and @scaisEdge!

Answer (score 0):

I would use the `date()` function and `count(distinct)` in MySQL:

```
select country_code, date(dr_timestamp) as dte, hour(dr_timestamp) as hr,
       count(distinct device_id)
from UsageGUI_datarecord
group by country_code, dte, hr;
```

If you want a particular date range, add a `where` clause.  If you want just hours, without the date, remove `dte` from the `select` and the `group by`.